# How to do concurrent guzzle http post request to rest api in laravel?

Tags: laravel, api, rest, concurrency, guzzle

I want to make concurrent Guzzle http requests in laravel to rest api i have users  in 100k i want to perform billing for users.
Currently my guzzle http is doing synchronous calls to rest api which is taking 6 hours to complete 100k post requests and the requests does not have any call backs they are just post request with users msisdn and unique id in json format.
How to do concurrent 50 requests per second so that billing is performed quickly.

```
Following is part of my code which i use taken from https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#concurrent-requests



$requests = function ($total) {
    $url = "url here";
    $auth = base64_encode($username . ":" . $password);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
    $msgdata =[
    'msisdn'=>$msisdn,
     $subscription 
    =>$subscriptionInfo]; 
    
    yield new Request('post', $url,
    [ 
    'headers' => 
     [ 
     'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
     'Authorization' => $authorizaton
     ],
    'body' => json_encode($msgdata)
    ]); 

    }
     $pool = new Pool($client, $requests(50), [
                        'concurrency' => 5,
                        'fulfilled' => function (Response $response, $index) {
                            // this is delivered each successful response
                            echo $response;
                        },
                        'rejected' => function (RequestException $reason, $index) {
                            // this is delivered each failed request
                            echo $reason;
                        },
                    ]);

                    // Initiate the transfers and create a promise
                    $promise = $pool->promise();

                    // Force the pool of requests to complete.
                    $promise->wait();
```

i am getting response as

```
"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized"
```

But request params are not incorect idk why it is giving response as incorect

Comment: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#concurrent-requests

Comment: first you need to know how many concurrent requests the api can handle at a time otherwise you get too many requests error

Comment: then you can use the GuzzleHttp\Pool object when you have an indeterminate amount of requests(here in your case 50) you wish to send.

Comment: i have tried @apokryfos link 
"You can use the GuzzleHttp\Pool object when you have an indeterminate amount of requests you wish to send." now the problem is all the params are corect but it is gving me unauthorized error from endpoint which means parameters are not correct.
following is my request:

$msgdata =['msisdn'=>$msisdn, $subscription =>$subscriptionInfo,"uid"=>$uid];
yield new Request('post', $url,[ 'headers' => [ 'Content-Type'  => 'application/json','Authorization' => $authorizaton],
                                'body' => json_encode($msgdata)]);

Comment: @bhucho the RestApi can handle more than 50 concurrent requests per second

Comment: edit your question to show what you have written in above comment

Comment: @bhucho i've edited my question, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the solution to my problem, the problem was in request header and body parameters.

changed this

```
 yield new Request('post', $url,
    [ 
    'headers' => 
     [ 
     'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
     'Authorization' => $authorizaton
     ],
    'body' => json_encode($msgdata)
    ]);
```

to

```
 yield new Request('post', $url,
    [ 
     'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
     'Authorization' => $authorizaton
     ],
json_encode($msgdata)
    );
```